# Deleting Jenkins Bindings?

Tags: jenkins

In order to pass environment variables to my build, I used the Jenkins Bindings Plugin.

However, I'd like to delete un-used Bindings.

How can I do that?

Note - posted on [jenkins-users google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/rZwfW4__nz0) too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Jenkins -> Credentials -> Select Binding -> Delete`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I believe that this answer succinctly answered the question that I posted. Please let me know what's unclear about it.